# php read images outside localhost on another disk

Tags: php, localhost

ok, this learning project will run only localy

winxp + service pack 3

xampp + PHP: 5.2.0

root folder: localhost/demo (C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\demo)

i need to run a script in my root, that will show me images from another hard disc on the same computer (not network drive, not shared)

the path of the files is: G:/folder1/folder2/folder3/file

I cannot point to that file to load directly into my demo application

if it is an image, show it

if it is a txt open it

etc

is this possible at all or should all files be inside root folder?

Comment: As you use the apache websever, take a look into the `Alias` directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#alias - that's exactly what it is for.

Comment: @hakre This should be an answer

Comment: @pinouchon: added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you use the apache websever, take a look into the [`Alias` directive <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) - that's exactly what it is for.

```
Alias /files G:/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

You can then access all files inside folder3 via `http://localhost/files/...`.

Comment: you both were almost correct - in my case i needed to make 2 modifications to my httpd.conf file

1) set the alias as posted by @hakre
2) make a directory
<Directory "G:/folder1/folder2/folder3">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

After that, restart apache and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way left click on wamp icon then choose Apache tab then alias directories then add an alias. A new window will open. Write the name of the alias then press enter and then write the right destination and press enter again. All wamp services will start automatically. Use the alias name you entered before to refer to the image source in your code like http://localhost/aliasname/...