# Can't load CSS and images if localhost folder is located on another disk

Tags: php, localhost

First, please do not mark my question as a duplicate of the question by the link [php read images outside localhost on another disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8023456/3208225) because after reading my question to the end you'll notice that my path to static files should be dynamic in my `index.php` file

I use the simplest PHP server on Windows starting it by a .VBS file with the CMD-command

```
php -S localhost:80
```

My .VBS file and `index.php` are located in a folder inside of the hard disk C and should be located there. So when I start the server, it uses the folder on disk C as the root localhost folder. But static files are and should be located on hard disk D.

I can successfully load static HTML files to the browser using the following PHP code in my index.php

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($path == '/') {
    $path = 'index';
}
$pathToStaticWebsite = 'D:/static_websites/website1/';
$page = file_get_contents($pathToStaticWebsite.$path.'.html');
echo $page;
?>
```

But HTML file has relative paths to CSS and images like `src="images/..."` and they are not being loaded. I've tried to add the line

```
$page = str_replace('images/','file:///'.$pathToStaticWebsite.'images/',$page);
```

before `echo`ing the page in the `index.php`, but it doesn't work, as I see because the server doesn't handle such local paths

How to resolve the problem?

ps. I mean without using `.htaccess` with path to `index.php` inside of the `website1` folder and bearing in mind that `index.php` as main app file may swicth us from `website1` to `website2`, so the path to static website folder is dynamic within `index.php`

Comment: The true way to handle this is to setup an actual webserver locally on your machine. Eventually, when you deploy, you will have to have the correct paths for the website.

Answer (score 0):

to have a system like you describe you will have to setup a webserver - `php -S` is intended to aid application development (where all files are stored within the given folder)

also it is not possible to request local files from http (http:// and file://)

Comment: Thank you. But again the path should be dynamic in index.php so that at one moment a user can switch to another website without restarting the server. Maybe there is a solution with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if it's used to load CSS and images?

Comment: -> it is of course possible to write a custom router for the server (http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

But at this point I think it will be easier to have ie nginx or apache running with different vhosts

Answer (score 0):

As What I Understanded From Your Question 
I hope That Can Help You I Use This To Locate The Project DIRECTORY And Get The System DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
 Because In Windows OS The DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is \
 And In The Mac OS And UNIX OS DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is /

```
<?php
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
?>
```